# Формы в AngularJS и передача данных в Django REST

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, django-rest-framework

Возникла проблема с отображением и обработкой формы.
При первоначальной загрузке формы в полях `field1` и `field2` стоят значения `[Object object]`. Изначально я никак их не заполняю. Также не работают `placeholder`-ы.

При попытке `submit` в консоли выводится ошибка

```
Error: cyclic object value
```

Если я вручную вбиваю какой-то текст в оба поля, то submit происходит  без ошибок.

Также возник вопрос - в каком виде передать данные на сервер? На сервере Django REST.

```
<div ng-app="someApp">
<div class="container"  ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
<form role="form" name="someForm" ng-submit="submit()">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="field1">Поле1</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input class="form-control required" type="text" placeholder="какой-то текст" name="field1" id="field1" ng-model="someForm.field1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="field2">Поле2</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input class="form-control required" type="text" placeholder="какой-то текст 2" name="field2" id="filed2" ng-model="someForm.field2"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Отправить" ng-disabled="someForm.$invalid"/>
             </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Контроллер

```
someApp.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { 
            $scope.submit = function(){
              console.log(angular.toJson($scope.someForm));
            }
        }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ангуляр посредством дерективы наделяет формы новыми свойствами. По-умочанию, каждая форма `form` это директива и новый контроллер. Задания имени `name` позволяет обращаться к этому контроллеру по имени.

Вам в вашем контроллере необходимо создать объект-хранилище полей.

```
$scope.formData = {};
```

А в `ng-model` прописать значения относительно этого объекта.

```
ng-model='formData.field1'
```

После этого в объекте `$scope.formData` вы будете иметь все введённые пользователем данные.

Comment: у меня вроде все так по коду, заменил вывод `console.log(angular.toJson($scope.someForm));` на `console.log($scope.someForm));`. Однако выводится куча мусора, непонятно, как выделить нужные данные для передачи в REST? И первоначальное значение все равно автоматически вбивается в поля как [Object object]

Comment: `[Object object]` убралось, `placeholder` работает, не знаю даже, почему, всего лишь добавил группу чекбоксов http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457685/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B-checkbox-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-angularjs Выходит, без минимальной инициализации будет все равно  `[Object object]`? Остается вопрос, как получить данные, как обычно из переменных в `$scope`, или есть более удобный способ? И как передать их в REST? Видимо, в JSON. Именно как форму, чтобы был смысл ее использовать