# Генерация группы checkbox для формы AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Как добавить группу чекбоксов на форму? 
Предположим, есть форма:

```
<form role="form" name="someForm" ng-submit="submit()">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="field1">Поле1</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input class="form-control required" type="text" placeholder="какой-то текст" name="field1" id="field1" ng-model="someForm.field1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="field2">Поле2</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input class="form-control required" type="text" placeholder="какой-то текст 2" name="field2" id="filed2" ng-model="someForm.field2"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Отправить" ng-disabled="someForm.$invalid"/>
             </div>
</form>
```

Пытаюсь добавить что-то вроде

```
<div class="control-group">
       <div class="controls" ng-repeat="field3 in someForm.fields">
             <input type="checkbox" ng-model="field3"/>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in fields">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="someForm.selectedFields[val.id]" />
</div>
```

в контроллере:

```
$scope.someForm = {};
$scope.someForm.selectedFields = {};
$scope.fields = [{'name': 'name1', id: 1}, {'name': 'name2', id: 2}];
```